# double escaping JSON not working - jackson

Tags: regex, spring-mvc, jackson

Thought it would be simple but doesn't seem to be. Can anyone work out how I can escape the regex expression in a JSON file when using Spring MVC 3.2 & Jackson 2.2? for example, the following regex;

```
{
  "regex": "^[\\S]{4}"
}
```

gives me

> ```
> 'org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>  Could not read JSON: Unrecognized character escape 'S' (code 83)'
> ```

. I expected that the first backslash escapes the second but from the error doesn't seem to be the case?

Thanks,

Ian.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark: Does `"regex": "^[\\\\S]{4}"` work?

Comment: Nope -had already tried that one but thanks...

Answer (score 0):

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = "{\"regex\": \"^[\\S]{4}\"}";
Map map = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference>(){});

This should work.